# Filling empty space with floating divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I some html like:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 200px; height: 20px">
  <div id="label" style="float: left">The text goes here, and it can get long</div>
  <div id="someImg1" style="float: right"><img ... /></div>
  <div id="someImg2" style="float: right"><img ... /></div>
</div>
```

So basically, I have a fixed width and height container, with some text that is pushed to the left of the container, and two images pushed up against the right end.

My question: I want the text to take up as much space as it needs on the left side, up to the images on the right side (if the text is long enough) without pushing the images off of the container. If the text can't fit, hiding the x-overflow of the text is fine (although showing a ... would be ideal, I don't know of an easy and quick way to know when to do this). I can't just make the label a fixed width with `overflow-x: hidden` because one or both of those images may actually not exist on the container, and the text should fill up as much space as it can.

Example: given text: "Here is my text, it is long though" should look like:

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | Here is my text, it is l +---+  +---+ |
 |                          +-1-+  +-2-+ |
 +---------------------------------------+
```

OR

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | Here is my text, it is long th  +---+ |
 |                                 +-2-+ |
 +---------------------------------------+
```

Depending on if image 1 is drawn on container or not

Comment: A picture/ascii diagram would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a fixed `width` on the text container with `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? `float` to the rescue!

http://jsfiddle.net/jZpWf/5/

EDIT: I can't test IE6, does it work now? (LINK CHANGED)

Comment: Do you HAVE to support IE6 anyway? Even MS is trying to push people off of it now...

Comment: unfortunately, almost 30% of my users use it

Comment: I'd say get a new job where you don't have to support legacy crap, but I'm in the same kind of position.

Comment: nope, sorry. After doing some reading there are known bugs in IE6 regarding floated elements in a div. If the container can't fit the contents issues arise (and no good solutions I can find)